# gthumb suddenly won't start

Tags: gthumb

gthumb, which had been working fine, suddenly won't start using the GUI and when run in terminal gives the following:

Could not load the mandatory extension 'cairo_io': Could not open the module “cairo_io”: libjxl.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm running ubuntu 20.04 on a DELL XPS-13.

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you install gthumb?

Comment: The reason I ask is because libjxl.so.0 or libjxl isn't found for Ubuntu as far as I can tell. Did you install libjxl from github or did you install gthumb from some other source besides the standard Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: I have always use d a standard installation method: either apt-get in a terminal or via the GUI.  I just read your post again and thought I should say that I didn't (purposely) install libjxl in any form.

Comment: I did an upgrade this morning using apt and timenow gthumb works again.  Thanks for your.

Comment: Sorry "timenow" should read: now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ubuntuhandbook ppa enabled, then you need to install the `jpeg-xl` package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install jpeg-xl
```

If that doesn't work, you can try to reinstall the non-ppa version of gthumb by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gthumb=3:3.8.0-2.1build1
```

If that works, you have two options.

**Option 1: remove the ppa.**

For example, if the ubuntuhandbook ppa is installed, run the following command to remove the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/apps
```

**Option 2: put the package version on hold until the ppa bugs are fixed.**

For example, to put the package version on hold, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-mark hold gthumb=3:3.8.0-2.1build1
```

To unhold the package number, run the following command:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold gthumb=3:3.8.0-2.1build1
```

---

Additionally, I strongly suggest filing a bug report with the ppa maintainer if a ppa is causing the issue. A recent update was made to the `jpeg-xl` package on June 15th and this may be the cause of the issue.

To determine which ppa is responsible for the package, run the following command:

```
apt-cache policy gthumb
```

look for the ppa and google the ppa name to find the launchpad page.

On the launchpad page, look for who to contact for bugs.

[image]